# Add product sku in URL

Tags: product, url, sku, product-urls

How can I dynamically change the url of a product?

Now I got this url

`www.domain.com/product-name.html`

I need to add SKU, to my url like this:

`www.domain.com/product-name-SKU.html`

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you can extend

`Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator`

class file.
Append product SKU into

`prepareProductUrlKey(), prepareProductDefaultUrlKey(),getUrlPath() function`.